# Unable to use WHERE with INSERT

Tags: sql-server

```
USE [Training]
GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.sysobjects where NAME = 'USP_insertNotesToGoal_RPTS' )
      DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_insertNotesToGoal_RPTS] 

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_insertNotesToGoal_RPTS] 
      @GoalNotes varchar(500),
      @UserName varchar(50),
      @GoalName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
  /*
  Author: Shivang Rana
  Description: To add notes to a goal
  Date:10-01-2015
  Version History:1.0
  Date      Purpose
  */
  declare @UserID int

  select UserID 
  from User_details 
  where UserName = @UserName

  insert into Goal_Details (GoalNotes) 
  values (@GoalNotes) 
  where GoalName = @GoalName and UserID = @UserID

  PRINT 'USP_insertNotesToGoal_RPTS'
END
GO
```

Comment: You need to use `UPDATE` and not insert in this case. Insert is used when you're creating a new record (row). When you need to update certain columns for an existing record, you need to use UPDATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a update statement, not an INSERT

Try replacing your insert with this

```
UPDATE Goal_Details SET
    GoalNotes = @GoalNotes
WHERE GoalName = @GoalName and UserID = @UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use update rather than insert.

As you need to update

```
   update table_name 
   set column_name=@parameter 
   where column_name=@parameter2
```